# What's the correct way of using JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a `JFrame` in which I should display a list of 30 reviews. Each review is a custom panel named `ReviewPanel`, and I am using an absolute layout. Using this code, I would expect to be able to scroll the p panel in order to view all of the reviews:

```
    public TestFrame() {
    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 934, 1103);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 916, 1056);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
    
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(p);
        p.setLayout(null);
    
        for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
            ReviewPanel review_panel = new ReviewPanel();
            review_panel.setLocation(0, i * review_panel.getHeight());
            p.add(review_panel);
        }
    
    }
```

The output, instead, is the following. I can see the first 3 reviews because of the size of the panel, but cannot scroll down to see the rest.

[image]

What can I do to fix this? I have also tried many alternatives but with no success.

Comment: `p.setLayout(null);` There's the problem. Don't. Use. `null`. Layouts. They ruin things generally, but especially for scroll panes.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). Note: I am skeptical of claims to the effect *"tried many alternatives"* when it comes to `null` layouts. Was one of those alternatives not .. looking at the ***plethora*** of threads in which they cause problems?!?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I know that `null` layouts are generally despised, but I don't understand how your answer can help me. It's not like you gave me an hint on how to use a different layout to solve my problem, you just told me I did the wrong thing. Also, I tried using a Grid Layout and a Box Layout, and both these layouts gave me different problems (for example, the Box Layout with vertical set up only showed a vertical list of Review Title). If you could give me a brief explanation of how I could manage to solve the problem by using a different layout, I would gladly do it.

Comment: Show your attempt, as a [mre], using a `GridLayout` to arrange the `ReviewPanel`. *"using a different layout"* You don't even seem to have taken in the part of my comment which mentions *"use layout managers, or **combinations** of them"*. Very few working GUIs have just one layout. Did you visit the linked question? Did you copy the code into an IDE, compile and run it? Did you *look* at the code? *"It's not like you gave me an hint"* It's not like you should not already have read enough questions to get lots of hints. This occurs so often there are plenty of discussions & examples. ..

Comment: .. The impression I am getting is that you expect us to spoon feed an exact solution for this GUI. Will you expect that with the *next* GUI? The *one after that*? It's time for you to 'pick up the ball & run with it. SO is not a code generation machine.

Comment: " If you could give me a brief explanation of how I could manage to solve the problem by using a different layout, I would gladly do it. "  This is the problem.  You need to learn how to use Java Swing as a tool.  If we just give you the answer, you're not going to learn anything.  Here's the Oracle tutorial, A Visual Guide to Layout Managers.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html  Oh, and @Andrew Thompson provided a link to a Stack Overflow answer that used multiple Swing layouts.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *"If we just give you the answer, you're not going to learn anything."* I have to admit I'm guilty of that occasionally. But I draw a line in the sand when people are using `null` layouts and hinting at wanting me to 'prove' it can be done using layouts. Then they need to show a concerted effort of *trying* to implement it with layouts before I'll jump back in.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you made the `ReviewPanel` yourself, seems like you already know how to use `LayoutManager`s (such as `BorderLayout`, `GridLayout`, etc...). So, in order to go along with the suggestions of more experienced members in the comments of your question, I am not going to give all the code for this, but just detailed directions on how you could, in my opinion, improve the user experience.

Here is the mockup I would implement if I were you:

[image: Suggested mockup]

That is:

1. A scrollable `JTable` on the left part of the container panel. It contains the reviews' author label, title label, *like* and *dislike* buttons, date label, etc...
2. Two `JTextArea`s in the right part of the container panel. One for the review's text and another for the review's feedback.

This way, the user would select a line from the `JTable` which would correspond to the review he/she wants to read (determined by author, title, date, whether he/she liked it or not, etc...). By selecting a line from the `JTable` then the upper `JTextArea` would be filled with the selected review's text and the lower one with the review's feedback. Either `JTextArea` may be editable or not, whether it is supposed to be or not. Also, *sorting* the reviews in the table by a specific column becomes more *natural* now (ie it is more obvious to the user that he may sort by author name for example, and is also easier to implement because of the `RowSorter` facility supported by `JTable` and other related methods such as `JTable`'s `setAutoCreateRowSorter` etc...).

I would also suggest:

1. The `JTextArea`s inside a `JScrollPane` each, in the case you don't know beforehand the maximum size the reviews' text and feedback can occupy.
2. A `JSplitPane` divider splitting the `JScrollPane` of each `JTextArea`, mainly because of letting the user adjust them to their needs and also because it seems like the review's feedback part size is not equal to the review's text part size.
3. The *like* and *dislike* function could be composed by 3 `JRadioButton`s in the same `ButtonGroup`. One button for *like*, one for *dislike* and one for *unspecified* (which would be the default value and the middle button). I guess we need an *unspecified* button to exist, in order to let the user *undo* their selection (if for example they select the *like* button, then it should be possible to return to the initial state of *unspecified*).

In case the feedback *is* the preference (*like*, *dislike*, etc...), so that there is only one `JTextArea`, then the mockup still stands, but this time with the two `JTextArea`s combined to one.

In case you wan't to learn more there are Oracle's corresponding tutorials (besides documentation):

1. [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) (take a look at the table of contents of this page for more focused tutorials about each `LayoutManager`).
2. [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).
3. [How to Use Split Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I really appreciate the help, I will look into it. Sorry for the late feedback.

Comment: Thank you too. There are some points missing I noticed: there's a `JLabel` missing to describe that the upper text area is for the review's text and the lower for the review's feedback, but I guess you will figure it out. Also, the table entries are empty for simplicity. If I understood correctly, the *feedback* is a user's input text?... I'm not sure. What do you mean *Sorry for the late feedback.*?

Comment: I didn't read at what time you answered my question, so I thought you had answered a few hours back. I meant "sorry for the late feedback on your answer to my question" hahahaha. Anyway, the review feedback would be the sum of positive and negative votes it has recieved, with each positive vote counting as 1 and a negative one counting as -1. It still is incomplete though since it should of course show said sum.

Comment: Ok. No *late feedback* was received then. Haha. As for the user's feedback it could be a new column in the `JTable`... For example, a column *Preference* as is now should exist to let the user select whether he/she liked it or not. Then the summary of the votes would be shown at a new read-only column in the `JTable`, named, for example, *Vote summary* (or simply *Feedback* as you said).